# How to copy a value inside an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an integer array and the fifth value should always be similar to the first value.
For example, if i have:

`int test[] ={1,2,3,4,1}`

and if I say:

`test[0]= 5`

The array should look like: `5 2 3 4 5`.

Is there some way to do this? I tried with pointers, but couldn't get a good result.

Comment: Can you show your attemp with pointers?

Comment: `test[0] = test[4] = 5;`?

Comment: Why not do test[4] = 5 also?

Comment: int int1 = 1;
 int int2 = 2;
 int int3 = 3;
 int int4 = 4;
 int *int5 = &int1;

 int test[] = {int1, int2, int3, int4,*int5};

I tried by using variables and making the 5. value a pointer to the first value. But when i change the variables the values in the array dont change

Comment: Why would you expect the array values to change along your variables, they are kept in different memory locations. Your assumptions are just wrong.

Comment: int int1 = 1; int int2 = 2; int int3 = 3; int int4 = 4; int *int5 = &int1; int test[] = {int1, int2, int3, int4,*int5} will not work because c style arrays can have only handle one type, so you have to insert in the array the integer pointed (*int5): so you "lost" the pointer. If you use a debugger it will be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

[Test it on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/x379v4YE1)
Using actual C++ syntax instead of C:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void print_list(std::array<int*, 5> const& list){
    for( auto const& item : list ){
        std::cout << *item << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main(){
    std::array<int, 4> n = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::array<int*, 5> list = {&n[0], &n[1], &n[2], &n[3], &n[0]};
    print_list(list);
    *list[0] = 3;
    print_list(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with integers but pointers would do the trick, see here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_array_of_pointers.htm

Something like:

```
int *sharedNumber = new int(1);
int* ptr[] = {sharedNumber, new int(2), new int(3), new int(4), sharedNumber};
cout<<"values are "<<*ptr[0]<<" "<<*ptr[4]<<"\n"; 
*sharedNumber = 5;
cout<<"values are "<<*ptr[0]<<" "<<*ptr[4]<<"\n";
```

Will show 'value is 1' and 'value is 5' for ptr[1] and ptr[4] - just make sure to delete initialised memory to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Why put them on the heap?

Comment: I don't trust the stack.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to achieve this effect for a custom wrapper type, but not for arrays:

Just implement a custom `[]` operator:

```
template<class ElementType, size_t arraySize>
class MyArray
{
public:
    using value_type = ElementType;

    constexpr MyArray() = default;

    constexpr MyArray(std::initializer_list<ElementType> arr)
    {
        std::copy_n(arr.begin(), (std::min)(arraySize, arr.size()), m_data);
    }

    constexpr size_t size() const
    {
        return arraySize;
    }

    constexpr ElementType& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        return m_data[index % arraySize];
    }

    constexpr ElementType const& operator[](size_t index) const
    {
        return m_data[index % arraySize];
    }
private:
    ElementType m_data[arraySize];
};

int main()
{
    MyArray<int, 4> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    std::cout << a[4] << '\n';
    a[0] = 5;
    std::cout << a[4] << '\n';
}
```

Note that this just "wraps around"; not only can you access the first element using index `4`, but for every index passed the remainder of the division by the array size is used as index. The second element of `MyArray<int, 4>` could be accessed using indices 1, 5, 9, 4449, ect.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way of doing what you want with the syntax you're providing. Your options, which would (minimally) alter your code are:

- Manually setting two elements to the same value (see the comments below your question);
- Writing a function for mutating elements that automatically synchronizes the first and fifth elements;
- Storing an array of pointers (which seems to be your attempt);
- Sharing state between elements of the array so that affecting one element would also change other elements, and that way "synchronizing" their values;
- Wrapping your array into a class that manages that array.

*It should seem obvious which solutions are, most likely, overkill.*

Here is a very simple simple implementation of the second option:

```cpp
void setElement(int* array, size_t index, int value)
{
    array[index] = value;
    if (index == 0)
        array[4] = value;
    if (index == 4)
        array[0] = value;
}
```

*Keep in mind that using `std::array`, `std::vector` or iterators would probably be a better choice than C-style arrays and raw pointers.*